# Is the expression "do not bother" polite?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, politeness

I have a client who is a public figure in politics. I am working with her on writing some content for social media. I'd like to tell her that she doesn't need to send me 60 quotes, and that 30 is very enough.

Is it polite to say "30 is totally fine for now, do not bother making the whole 60"?

Is "do not bother" a polite expression, or is it too familiar ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: "Please do not go to the trouble of..." would be better.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: *Do not bother* is bad only when the message is bad: Do not bother to come in on Monday (You're fired.)

Answer (score 1):

"Do not bother" is not a completely formal expression, hence I wouldn't use it while communicating with people such as my boss.
You can use it with clients though, if the manner of conversation is slightly friendly between you and them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Would you have a more "formal" way to say that ? I am not sure indeed I can use such expression with her.

Comment: @Bowa Simply use "no need for making all 60"

Answer (score 1):

"Do not bother" is not really formal and I'd really not use it in written form (letter, emails, IM...) because it can even come across as rude depending on the region your client is from.

I'd use

"30 is totally fine for now, there is no need for making all 60" (short and clear) or

"30 is totally fine for now, no need to go to the trouble of making all 60" ("fluffier", coming across more as if you don't want to give her extra work)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Very helpful :)